# LOAD_FILE returns only null

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-loadfile

**I want to insert the image to the database with this query:**

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE('/Users/juliagaskevich/cool-background.svg');
```

**I checked that:**

- File size < max_allowed_packet.
- File has read, write and execute permissions to everyone.
- The user, what I'm using to execute the query has FILE privilege.
- `mysql> show variables like "secure_file_priv"` returns NULL.

**System configuration:**

macOS Monterey, version 12.5, chip Apple M1

MySQL Ver 8.0.29 for macos12 on arm64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
MySQL Config:

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql_deamon
slow_query_log_file = my-slow-query.log
slow-query-log
log-queries-not-using-indexes
general_log_file = my-GENERAL.log
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824
```

Also, I tried to fix my problem with guys' ideas, but...

---

> 1.vi my.cnf
>
> secure-file-priv=/mysql/dataload(Change /mysql/dataload to your own
> directory.)
>
> 2.restart mysql service

[Changed my.cnf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alcmt.jpg)

[Changed my.cnf (without quotes in secure-file-priv path)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS4cP.png)

---

> The statement SELECT LOAD_FILE(...) delivers one string. To INSERT,
> use the statement LOAD DATA INFILE ...

[1290 ERROR with null secure_file_priv result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3tDG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***SOLVING***

If you are using mac, you have the /etc/my.cnf (file, where is MySQL config stored), so put there this string `secure_file_priv = ""`

Run this to apply config changes `mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --validate-config --log_error_verbosity=2` **AND IF** you have any warnings or errors fix it, because it can solve your problem

If you are using some different user than root, the user have to have a FILE privileges `mysql> GRANT privilege ON privilege_level TO account_name;`, for example `mysql> GRANT FILE ON *.* TO pizzaadmin;`

---

The most important thing: **To apply changes, you have to restart mysqld.**

There are few steps:

1. stop it (You can do this with this command `mysqladmin shutdown`)
2. start again (You can do this with just executing `mysqld` in terminal)

Answer (score 0):

1.vi my.cnf

secure-file-priv=/mysql/dataload(Change /mysql/dataload to your own directory.)

2.restart mysql service

Comment: I have been adding the "secure-file-priv = /usr/local/mysql-8.0.29-macos12-arm64/Uploads/" to my.cnf, reloaded laptop, restarted mysql server and... When I run query "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";" it still returns NULL 

Check updated answer. I attached details

Comment: @SCorpi Do not add ""to the parameter, that is, secure-file-priv =/mysql/dataload.

Comment: I deleted quotes, but it still doesn't work(
Check the schreenshot #2 for more details

Comment: @SCorpi  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

Answer (score 0):

The statement `SELECT LOAD_FILE(...)` delivers one string.  To `INSERT`, use the statement `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`

Comment: Ahhhh, I got an error:
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement, but --secure-file-priv is null...

Check please question update